# Are universal adapters safe to use for gaming on a Lenovo Y700?

Tags: laptop, lenovo-laptop, adapter

I have a Lenovo Y700 and I travel a lot by my car, is it safe to run my laptop on a universal adapter so I can run and charger the laptop from the car battery?

I don’t want any damage to happen on my laptop, and I want to play games while using it

An adapter like [this adapter](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/100w-universal-laptop-ac-power-charger_60243902391.html):

[image]

Comment: Why do you think a power adapter that works for your laptop somehow won’t work? If you are concerned, don’t buy a discount power adapter but rather spend a bit more $$$ for a quality brand that works with your laptop?

Comment: Money is not a problem ,My problem,is this option safe or not

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your laptop power adapter and it and your laptops power draw.

If you are using a 135 watt power brick, your car should handle it without tripping the fuse.

The power inverter shown in your picture, I wouldn't trust it.  No need to have your car's electrical system fried or catch fire due to a manufacturing issue.

What you are looking for is a 150 watt "**pure sine wave**" inverter.

You can go up to 250 watts, but I wouldn't recommend much more than that.

You may also want to verify there's a 15 amp fuse connected to your cigarette lighter, just to be sure.